# Print file name from type=file button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a regular button that onclick activates the type=file button and works properly, as in that it successfully opens the choose a file menu and then selects a file, but it doesnt say the name of the file anywhere. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div class="div-table" align="center">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <div class="div-table-row" align="center">
            <div class="div-table-col" align="right"> Upload Doc File:   </div> 
            <div class="div-table-col" align="left">
                <input type="button" id="my-button" value="Select Doc File" class="button" >
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" src="#" onchange="getFilePath())">
            </div>
            <script> 
                $('#my-button').click(function(){
                    $('#file').click();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Id just like to pop up and show the file name next to the button or something so the user knows that the files been selected. Thanks

Comment: What does getFilePath() do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the name of a file you picked for an upload before submitting the file?

```
$('input:file#avatar').change(function () {
    var file_name = $(this).val();
    if (file_name.length > 10) {
        file_name = file_name.substring(0, 10) + '...';
    }
});
```

`file_name` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've tried this code out - hope this helps

```
    <form action="" method="POST" type="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="filename" style="display:none;" onchange="getPath()">
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="openpath()">
</form>
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
var inputName = document.getElementById('filename');
var dis = document.getElementById('display');

function openpath(){
    inputName.click();
}

function getPath() {
     var imgPath;

     imgPath = inputName.value;
     imgPath = imgPath.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
     dis.innerHTML = imgPath;

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the filename after the button like an actual browse button does, you can do something like this (sorry, I don't jquery):

```
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var fn = '<span>' + this.value.replace(/^.*?([^\\\/]*)$/, '$1') + '</span>';
  document.getElementById('my-button').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', fn);
}, false);
```